# Optimize City and Address Capturing RegEx

Tags: regex

I'm working with a text file that contains many lines of data. The format that I'm getting this in is pretty nasty, but it is consistent, which is why I'd like to use a RegEx here.

Each property is space delimited (5 spaces), starting with state, then city, then user type, then the user address (followed by how many years they've been at the address), then a GUID. For security purposes I've modified the addresses, but each line follows the same format :

```
[{     OH     Crestline     Reseller     (1234 Alvarez Dr., 4)     a6fa960c-921a-40e6-a5ab-30cc7fb83907     }]
[{     AZ     Marana     Distributor     (1234 Union St., >1)     1f2a9252-cbac-4e17-8d4c-d5eaebb5f6b7     }]
[{     MI     Lansing     Reseller     (1234 Westmore Ave., 11)     5736c1c0-2e23-43cd-8765-c48fbe51ffee     }]
```

What I'm interested in capturing here is the city and the address with the number of years. I've written the following RegEx to achieve this :

```
\[\{[ ]{5}[A-Z]{1,}[ ]{5}([A-Za-z]{1,})[ ]{5}(?:Reseller|Distributor){1,}[ ]{5}\(([0-9]{1,}[ ][A-Za-z]{1,}[ ][A-Za-z.,]{1,}[ ][>0-9]{1,})
```

Using the above expression, and the first line from the example data, the RegEx captures `Crestline` in the first group, and `1234 Alvarez Dr., 4` in the second.

**My question :**

Is there a cleaner or more condensed way of writing this expression, so that it can still capture those two pieces of information from the line?

Comment: These were all good answers, but nmclean's was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said the format is consistent, so you can remove the format validation from the pattern. Judging by the type of data, you can probably also make the assumption that `(` doesn't appear anywhere other than before the address. In that case you could condense it by quite a lot:

```
[ ]{5}.+?[ ]{5}([^ ]+).+\(([^)]+)
```

Breakdown:

- `[ ]{5}.+?[ ]{5}` - skip 2 separate groups of 5 spaces (with non-greediness in between to ensure it's only the first two groups)
- `([^ ]+)` - capture a group of non-space characters (this is the city)
- `.+\(` - skip ahead until a `(` is found
- `([^)]+)` - capture inside the parentheses (this is the address with years)

Comment: Yes! This is great - it maintains the two capture groups perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You can just a bit shorter and more efficient expression like this:

```
\[\{\s{5}[A-Z]+\s{5}(\w+)[^\(]+\(([^,]+),[^0-9]+([0-9]+)\)[^\}]+\}\]
```

This will capture the city name in group 1, the street address in group 2 and the number of years he/she spent at that address in group 3.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use:

```
\[\{\s{5}[A-Z]{2}\s{5}(.+?)\s{5}.+?\s{5}\(([^)]+)\)
```

The city will be in group 1 and the address and number of year in group 2.

**explanation:**

```
The regular expression:

(?-imsx:\[\{\s{5}[A-Z]{2}\s{5}(.+?)\s{5}.+?\s{5}\(([^)]+)\))

matches as follows:

NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(?-imsx:                 group, but do not capture (case-sensitive)
                         (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with . not
                         matching \n) (matching whitespace and #
                         normally):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \[                       '['
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \{                       '{'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s{5}                    whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (5
                           times)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [A-Z]{2}                 any character of: 'A' to 'Z' (2 times)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s{5}                    whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (5
                           times)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    .+?                      any character except \n (1 or more times
                             (matching the least amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s{5}                    whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (5
                           times)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  .+?                      any character except \n (1 or more times
                           (matching the least amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s{5}                    whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (5
                           times)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \(                       '('
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^)]+                    any character except: ')' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \)                       ')'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Using this expression captured the city AND user type in the first group - very close, but not quite what I needed - great explanation though.

Comment: @X3074861X: Yes, you're right, I just miss an occurrence of `\s{5}`